# How to build wxWidgets on Mac OS with zlib?

Tags: macos, wxwidgets

I have downloaded wxWidgets 3.1.2 source code to Mac PC. I try to build it by instruction in its file docs/ios/install.md:

```
mkdir build-cocoa-debug
cd build-cocoa-debug
../configure --enable-debug
make
```

Output files are located in folder build-cocoa-debug/lib. I see in this folder thirdparty libs: libwxjpeg-3.1.a, libwxpng-3.1.a, libwxregexu-3.1.a, libwxscintilla-3.1.a and libwxtiff-3.1.a. But I cannot find among them zlib. In Windows build of wxWidgets zlib is present (but I downloaded it as binary, not as source).

Using option --with-zlib do not help:

```
../configure --enable-debug --with-zlib
```

zlib is still absent in output folder.

Comment: try `--with-zlib=builtin`

Comment: Thank you. This option solves the problem.

Comment: What exactly is/was the problem though? I.e. why do you think you need to have `libwxzlib-3.1.a` in the first place?

Comment: My project uses this lib. On Windows it is built successfully. But on Mac it cannot find functions from this lib because this lib is absent in wxWidgets.